# Does one still get Schar for trying to do a Mitzvah even if they didn’t end up doing it properly?

Tags: mitzvah, reward-punishment

Presumably a person would still get some Schar for putting in the effort for doing a Mitzvah even if they didn’t end up doing it properly, right? Lfum Tzaarah Agra?

Comment: If a person tried to do a mitzva but was prevented from doing it, they get credited as if they did it. See this related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97763/is-there-any-reward-for-the-intent-or-attempt-to-do-a-mitzvah. Could you explain your question better - what are the circumstances?

Answer (score -2):

As yidden, there is a klal machshava kimaisa - that the thought is like doing the action. So if we even think to do a mitzva, we get schar.

Comment: I do not remember where the gemara is.

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, but I suspect it's because it's not clear this is what Raphael is asking. It sounds like it might be a performance thing, in which case ignorance of how to perform it properly might get in the way of this principle. BTW the gemara is Kiddushin and I linked an answer about it in my OP comment

Comment: Well if you try to fulfill a mitzvah (albeit improperly), this clearly shows you had intent to do it in your mind, and therefore should get the schar in accordance with the Gemara cited

Comment: @KovyJacob I believe it appears in Kidushin 40a.

Comment: @ShmuelKoppel Thanks!